# How to find 2D image points corresponding to the 3D stereoscopic points

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

How to project gaze vectors onto a virtual plane that is perpendicular to the line of sight. Given the gaze vector coordinates

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although I've already made some edits to your question, you may want to properly format future questions so it is easier for people to understand your question. You can find out more about how to ask a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Questions: (1) Are the eyes among the points returned by your stereo device?  (1) Is the eye tracker fixed with respect to the stereo device? (3) Are the stereo device and eye tracker synchronized, or, equivalently, do you have precise timestamps for the points produced by both devices?